# Hyper-V: my custom virtual switch disappears from time to time

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

On my Windows 10 Pro x64 PC, I have Hyper-V with multiple VMs. Some VMs use a custom virtual switch (let's call it "MySwitch"), which I need so that I can set it to type "External" and have my VMs ports exposed.

The issue is that, from time to time (this already happened 4-5 times), **"MySwitch" disappears and the VMs using it cannot start anymore**

[image]

The message is a bit cryptic, but the issue is that "MySwitch" doesn't actually exist anymore. Meaning: when this happens, I can no longer see it under "Network connections".

This never happens with the default virtual switch created by Hyper-V, only with my own.

I'm having an hard time pinpointing the cause:

- today is February 24th, so we are far away from "patch Tuesday" (I checked to be sure: no patch were installed recently)
- I didn't do any maintenance of sort recently, so it's unlikely to be some side-effect of something I did interactively
- I Googled it: nothing useful came back

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find anything in the Hyper-V vSwitch event logs through Event Viewer?

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for your tip. Under `Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch/Operational` I just have a lot of `Verbose`-level stuff, but nothing relevant.

Comment: Does reboot fix the problem of resources?

Comment: I use an External Switch in Hyper-V on Windows  11 and it stays put.  Have you tried removing, restarting, and re-adding Hyper-V?  If you try this, make very sure you have machine backups

Comment: @harrymc The error is misleading. The problem is related to the switch no longer existing

Comment: @John If nothing else come up, I'll try to reinstall Hyper-V. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Try [this solution](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2081140-hyper-v-server-missing-net-adapter).